# Sublime 2 append current date to filename

Tags: sublimetext2, build-system

I'm trying to use YUICompressor to add the current date to the compressed file. Here's my code

```
{
    "cmd": ["java", "-jar",  "${packages}/User/YUI Compressor/build/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar", "$file", "-o", "${file_base_name}%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~12,2%-min.${file_extension}", "--charset", "utf-8"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

But when I run it, I get sublime trying to write the date part of the string verbatim as the file name. Is something like this possible? How would I go about it?

Comment: What happens if you add the `"shell": True` option?